# Vim Looks Very Weird When Using chcp 65001

Tags: cygwin

I've needed to switch to `chcp 65001` to properly display some Unicode characters.

However, I've noticed that my Vim isn't displaying characters properly when `chcp` is set to `65001` as opposed to `437`.

This is what it looks like:

[image: Screenshot]

Which Vim setting do I need to change to have it properly display with `chcp 65001`?

**Update: It appears that this is an issue specific to Console2 the command-line program I'm using. It does not happen in cmd when I set the chcp to 65001. Any suggestions are welcome.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by adding `set encoding=utf-8` to `.vimrc` (called `_vimrc` on Windows).

Comment: That's the better solution, limiting yourself to only 256 possible characters is bound to cause problems.